# How to download the LATEST artifact from jfrog Artifactory repository to jenkins declarative pipeline without plugin using Curl command?

Tags: jenkins

How to download **latest** artifacts from jFrog repository. Without using Jenkins plugins I am using curl command.
My jfrog artifact format: build-156.zip
Jenkins Declarative pipeline syntax

```
        script {                                                                            
            
            sh "curl -u admin:password@123 'https://<ARTIFACTORY_URL>/path/to/repository/$LATEST_ARTIFACT'"                             
        }
```

Comment: Isn't your code working?

Comment: Hi, Yes it's not working

Comment: @swethap What error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the artifact one should point to the repo or artifact itself, as is, in groovy:

```
def _artifact = sh(script: "curl -X GET http://${URL}:8082/artifactory/${REPOSITORY}/${PLATFORM}/${ENV}/stage/${PROJECT}/${VERSION}/${ARTIFACT} -o ${ARTIFACT}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

or with authentication on the command line:

```
curl -u admin:xxxx -XGET http://192.168.50.67:8082/artifactory/jfrog-support-bundle/ --output download.zip
```

Refs:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveArtifact

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).